# How to forward Telegram messages to e-mail instantly?

Tags: email, telegram

How to forward Telegram messages from a group or channel to an email address?!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/6l64ga/way_to_send_an_email_with_telegram_messages/

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this as well, but never found a solution.

I've got an idea: one could create a Telegram client that runs in the background, receives messages and forwards to email; but the Telegram API is too difficult for me.

Or one could build a wrapper around telegram-cli. But first I should figure how to run it in Windows through the Linux subsystem or Cygwin.